# React Native json to flatlist view data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to put the data into the flatlist to make it look good for a react native mobile app. The item.abc.b part seems to throw an error of object not found. Can you explain where am I going wrong?
Data looks something like this:

```
<GridView
             text='How are you feeling?'
             feelings= {[
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Angry",
                  "checkinElementId": "3157"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Scared",
                  "checkinElementId": "3158"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Sad",
                  "checkinElementId": "3159"
                }
              }
                          ]}
             columns='3'
             selected={this.state.selected}/>
   The way FlatList is being used:
  `
</View>

           <FlatList
           data:  this.props.feelings,
           renderItem={ ({item})  =>  
                            (<View style {styles.GridViewBlockStyle} 
                         onPress={this._updateSelected.bind(this,item)}>
                                                   <Text style= 
     {styles.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}>

          {item.node.checkinElement}//this line is giving out error
                                                   </Text>
                                       </View>)
                                   }
          // customisable #columns in each grid
          numColumns={this.props.columns}
          />
      </View>
```

Comment: Do you like to show only abc data or from whole array?

Comment: As per the modified post, I want to show the item.node.checkinElement

Comment: Add extra { } around `{item.node.checkinElement}` to make it like this: `{{item.node.checkinElement}}`

Comment: Just tried it. It throws token unexpected error at that point. I also tried {`${item.node.checkinElement}`} that throws undefined object error just like the simple {} one

Comment: You're missing an "=" after "style" in this line: `(<View style {styles.GridViewBlockStyle}` - see my answer below which includes that "=" character

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is supplied correctly, and that your styles are also defined, the solution may be as simple as adding `(` and `)` around your `renderItem` arrow function. See below where I have added parenthesis:

```
</View>
    <FlatList
      data: this.props.feelings,
      renderItem={ ({item}) => 
          (<View style={styles.GridViewBlockStyle}> /* <-- Add ( here */
            <Text style={styles.GridViewInsideTextItemStyle}>        
                {{item.node.checkinElement}} /* <-- Add extra { and } */
            </Text>
           </View>) /* <-- Add ) here */
      }
      keyExtractor={item => item.checkinElementId}
      numColumns={this.props.columns} />
</View>
```

By adding the `(` and `)` as shown above, this means that "everything between the ( and ) is returned as the result of the arrow function". It's a short hand equivilant of:

```
({ item }) => {
    return (<View> ... </View>)
}
```

For more information on this, see the [Advanced Syntax example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax) for arrow functions

Comment: I tried wrapping up the view tag around () and adding it as a return statement but that did not work out. The styles and data is fine. Its throwing an object undefined error. Let me modify the code to show you the data and the structure

Comment: @NirajMotiani please see the addition of { and } , as well as the inclusion of the `=` that you are missing before `<Text style`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your data. You are passing array into object. So it will create an issue.

Your feelings data should be:

```
feelings= [
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Angry",
                  "checkinElementId": "3157"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Scared",
                  "checkinElementId": "3158"
                }
              },
              {
                "node": {
                  "checkinElement": "Sad",
                  "checkinElementId": "3159"
                }
              }
                          ]
```

You have set array into object without key. So Flatlist won't data to print. So it will be crashed.

Below is how I used them:

```
   <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    (<Text> {item.node.checkinElement}</Text>)
                }                  
            />
```

Hope this will help you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. This was my very first time asking a question and I really respect the stackoverflow community. I got it. The syntax everywhere and the data passing was correctly done. There were a few other threads that were trying to access the data before it was available causing an object non existing error